# forever loop sql

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql

I am trying to find all staff not logged on in the last 6 months so I have this code. It seems to be looping forever but I'm not sure why

```sql
--select all staff not logged on in the last 6 months
SELECT
[fkStaffId],
[dteLogon]
FROM
[dbo].[tbl_Staff_Logon]
WHERE
[fkStaffId]
NOT IN
(--select all staff logged on in the last 6 months
    SELECT DISTINCT
    [fkStaffId]
    FROM
    [dbo].[tbl_Staff_Logon]
    WHERE
    [dteLogon] > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) --this is a list of each staffID
                                               --logged on in the last 6 months
)
ORDER BY [dteLogon] DESC
```

anybody got any idea why?

if i just execute

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    [fkStaffId]
    FROM
    [dbo].[tbl_Staff_Logon]
    WHERE
    [dteLogon] > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

on it's own, I get a sensible sized list of 309 lines which is about the number I'm expecting, however, the last time I tried to run the entire code, it was still executing after 25 minutes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do a `GROUP BY`, and use `HAVING` to only return users who have not logged in recently:

```
SELECT 
    [fkStaffId], MAX([dteLogon])
FROM
    [dbo].[tbl_Staff_Logon]
GROUP BY [fkStaffId]
HAVING MAX([dteLogon]) < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems to do the trick. I have only been writing SQL for the last 6 months. I wish I could get better at it.